# ¿Como evitar que un usuario que tiene acceso a sus datos en la tabla de usuarios pueda acceder a los demás registros de la tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, cuenta-usuario

He intentado buscar esta pregunta y no la he encontrado, espero que no esté duplicada.
Soy un poco novato y necesito algunas aclaraciones. Gracias por la paciencia.

*Un usuario* entra en un sitio web dispuesto *a registrarse*. A través de una solicitud envía sus datos al servidor donde un programa los recibe y los introduce en la BD usando (el programa) las credenciales del administrador de la BD. En ese momento(el programa), además, crea un nuevo usuario en la base de datos con los privilegios de acceso correspondientes. Al hacer esto, el usuario también tendrá acceso a todos los registros de la tabla Usuarios. ¿Cómo puedo evitar esto? Aunque se tratara de filtrar sus consultas a través de procedimientos, el usuario, al estar registrado, tendría acceso a ellos solo con saber la ip del servidor de BD, ¿no es cierto?

**¿Por qué no hago que el usuario siempre tenga que pasar a través de las credenciales del administrador y evito registrarlo en la BD (en su esquema) internamente?**
Sencillamente porque, ya que estoy aprendiendo, quisiera primero saber si puede haber una estrecha relación entre el concepto de un usuario de una red social(por ejemplo) y el mecanismo de usuario de una BD. Si esta relación puede existir supongo que será buena usarla para aprovechar todas las funciones de la Base de Datos como por ejemplo las Vistas.
Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: **Al hacer esto, el usuario también tendrá acceso a todos los registros de la tabla Usuarios.** No, no es cierto.  El cuento que cree cuentos por otros usarios puede tener más acceso a las tablas como los demas.  Usualmente, la mayoria de usarios no tiene ningún acceso a la tabla de usarios.

Comment: @Duston , hola, perdón, pero no te he entendido. Según tengo entendido no es posible restringir el acceso a una única fila o registro. Es decir, si concedo permisos de acceso solo a la tabla **baseDeDatos.Usuarios**, el usuario podría acceder a todos los datos de la tabla Usuarios y solo a los de la tabla Usuarios, ¿no?

Comment: Efectivamente! Una solución a este problema suele ser crear vistas, donde si que puedes dar acceso a ciertas consultas predefinidas y de este modo evitas que puedan modificar/ver otros datos dentro de la misma tabla

Comment: @FER31 En el ejemplo que pones el usuario no tiene acceso a los datos de la tabla Usuarios. El usuario ni siquiera sabe que esa tabla existe. Entre el usuario y la base de datos hay un software intermedio que se encarga de extraer los datos que pertenecen a ese usuario y ese software es el que tiene las credenciales de la base de datos guardadas de forma segura.

Comment: Creo que tenes un error de concepto.. como podria acceder a todos los datos de una tabla (aunque tenga permisos de select) si toda interaccion con la base de datos se da a traves de tu sistema???

Comment: @ICIM , ok, creo que ya entiendo. Entonces ¿en vez de dar acceso a los usuarios a la tabla **BaseDeDatos.usuarios**, puedo crear una Vista  **unicoUsuario** y dar al Usuario acceso únicamente a esa Vista?

Comment: Si, es más puedes programar una vista para que cada uno de los usuarios tenga acceso a sus datos usando una variable de usuario por ejemplo el id. Ahora y coincidiendo con los 2 comentarios anteriores si tienes un sistema que habla con la DB puedes ahorrarte todo este proceso y gestionarlo directamente en tu programa, que ni sabemos cuál es,  ni en que consiste. Seguramente podamos ayudarte a crear un sistema mejor si nos das más datos y entendemos que estas montando

Comment: Normalmente cuando explican las DB, lo hacen con ejemplos que implica el registro de alguna persona o usuario. Además incorporan diagramas entidad/relación donde se da una relación como " _usuario_ ingresa _perfil_ ". Al principio, al estudiante, le cuesta discernir entre estos usuarios conceptuales, de los usuarios de las DB (los que se crean así `CREATE USER` ).
Ambos usuarios pueden coincidir en pequeños proyectos, pero ahora dudo de una base de datos con millones de usuarios, y que tenga creados millones de usuarios físicos(no sé si se dicen así, los que son creados con `CREATE USER` )

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero deberías explicar un poco que base de datos estás usando, aunque todas se parecen, te daré el ejemplo con Oracle, para una mayor seguridad los usuarios no se crean en tablas, se crean directamente sobre el gestor y se les dan privilegios. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
CREATE USER empresa IDENTIFIED BY contraseña;
GRANT DBA TO empresa;
```

Creamos los usuarios con sus respectivos privilegios:

```
CREATE USER secretaria IDENTIFIED by 12345;

GRANT SELECT ON empresa.Tabla1 TO secretaria;
GRANT INSERT ON empresa.Tabla2 TO secretaria;
GRANT UPDATE ON empresa.Tabla3 TO secretaria;
```

Aquí podemos ver qué el usuario secretaria no puede hacer CRUD sobre todas las tablas, en cada tabla solo tiene un permiso.

Esto es común en aplicaciones de escritorio que usen Oracle, para aplicaciones web se almacenan los usuarios en tablas dado que los framework facilitan los roles y privilegios, aunque se puede hacer como lo explique  anteriormente.

Comment: Más que a un SGBD en concreto me pregunto el modo habitual de hacerlo y tu (si se me permite) los has distinguido, para escritorios o web y eso ya es algo, pero si lo prefieres usemos Oracle o Mysql. Si exacto, yo prefiero según el código de tu ejemplo. Me parece más seguro y también creo que se puede sacar provecho y ahorrar alguna que otra regla de negocio. La cuestión es: 1 Si afectaría al rendimiento un número muy elevado de usuarios (Un millón, por ejemplo), y 2: Si existe un número máximo de usuarios que la BD puede tener en su tabla;  **mysql.user** (de optar por mysql)

Comment: 1.El rendimiento no se vería afectado, y si lo fuera no sería nada de que preocuparse. 2. En MySQL no se determina por número de registros, es decir, puede que una tabla tenga menos registros que otra pero si tiene muchos más campos posiblemente será más pesada.

Comment: Además, podrías complementar ambas formas de crear usuarios, es decir, crear un usuario1 directamente en la BD como te comenté y a partir todos los usuarios que tengan los mismos privilegios que el usuario1 pueden acceder a la aplicación con ese usuario, claramente con credenciales diferentes que se guardarían en una tabla de la BD principal.

Comment: En la tabla **mysql.user ** he contado 51 campos. ¿Esto es mucho contando que podría haber un millón de usuarios? Pero lo cierto es que salvo checar o actualizar algún valor de un campo de esta tabla, la mayoría de las acciones sobre esta tabla son las que realiza el SGBD al comprobar si el usuario coincide y si sus privilegios son válidos para hacer las acciones que pretenda hacer, y doy por hecho que esto está ya bastante optimizado.

Comment: Perdón, contesté sin leer el siguiente comentario. ¿Te refirieres a crear grupos de usuario uniendo ambas formas?

Comment: Con respecto a los 51 campos estos no serían problema, a nivel empresarial se manejan tablas con muchos campos. Y respecto a lo óptimo, ten en cuenta que el SGBD no necesita estar verificando cada campo del usuario sino únicamente la acción que pretendas realizar, es por eso que sería muy óptimo y además extremadamente seguro.

Comment: Si, es común utilizar grupos de usuarios, es decir, en una tabla "común" guardas la información personal, y le añades un campo de tipo de usuario, con ese tipo de usuario tendrían la cadena de conexión a la BD, supongo que ninguna aplicación tendrá demasiados roles como para estar creando muchos usuarios con exactamente los mismos privilegios.

Comment: Estupendo entonces. Me alegra usar este método pues me satisface más. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Te doy votos.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Cómo dato si en algún momento pasas de usuarios comunes como personas a organizaciones, se usan otros niveles de seguridad que se denominan multinquilinos.